# Data Dissapearing in Django on validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I am trying to create nested objects (documentregulation) when I create a Document object. To achieve this, I have overwritten the create method on the DocumentSerializer, as per Django Docs. However, when I attempt `validated_data.pop('documentregulation_set')`, it is empty, even when it is populated in the incoming `request.data` of my view. Is there something causing my incoming data to not be validated? How would I go about debugging this if so?

// serializers.py

```
class DocumentRegulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentRegulation
        fields = ('regulation',)

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    documentregulation_set = DocumentRegulationSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('documentregulation_set', 'id', 'name', 'file', 'text', 'uploaded_at')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'uploaded_at': {'read_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        documentregulation_set = validated_data.pop('documentregulation_set')   

        # create document first
        document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # serialize associated regulations
        for documentregulation in documentregulation_set:
            # get ID of newly-created document, use for relation    
            #documentregulation['regulation'] = documentregulation['id']
            DocumentRegulation.objects.create(document=document, **documentregulation)
        return document
```

//views.py

```
class DocumentView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def create(self, request):
        #pprint(self.request.FILES['profile_pic'])
        request.data['documentregulation_set'] = json.loads(request.data['documentregulation_set'])
        request.data['documentdomain_set'] = json.loads(request.data['documentdomain_set'])
        pprint(request.data)
        document = DocumentSerializer(data=request.data)

        if document.is_valid():
            document.save()
            return Response(document.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(document.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my incoming data (printed in `request.data`) looks like:

```
 {'documentregulation_set': [{'label': 'Regulation 1',
                              'regulation': 2,
                              'value': 2},
                             {'label': 'Regulation 2',
                              'regulation': 4,
                              'value': 4}],
  'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test.docx >,
  'name': 'testing',
  'text': 'test'}
```

but then my validated data prints out to be:

```
 {'documentregulation_set': [],
  'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test.docx >,
  'name': 'testing',
  'text': 'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with the validation of the `documentregulation_set` field in the `DocumentSerializer` serializer. But you can escape the validation in the Meta Class as:

```py
  class Meta:
    model = Document
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_kwargs = {
      'documentregulation_set': {'validators': []} # escape validation
    }
```

If you need to write custom validators have a look at [Writing custom validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators)

So the final serializer looks like:

```py
class DocumentRegulationSerializere(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  """Serializers for DocumentRegulation object"""

  class Meta:
     model = DocumentRegulation
     fields = ('regulation',)


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  """Serializer for Document objects"""
  documentregulation_set = DocumentRegulationSerializere(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Document
     fields = ('documentregulation_set', 'id', 'name', 'file', 'text', 'uploaded_at')
    extra_kwargs = {
      'id': {'read_only': True},
      'uploaded_at': {'read_only': True},
      'documentregulation_set': {'validators': []} # escape validation
    }

  def create(self, validated_data):
    doc_reg = []
    document_regulation_set = validated_data.pop('documentregulation_set')
    document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for document_regulation in document_regulation_set:
      reg = DocumentRegulation.objects.create(**document_regulation)
      reg.save()
      doc_reg.append(reg)

    document.documentregulation_set.add(reg)
    return document
```

**View**

```py
class DocumentView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  """List or create new Document ojects"""
  queryset = Document.objects.all()
  serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
```